# How to make <img> and <md-card> responsive in angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design, material-design, angular-material

I'm displaying dynamic content by looping with `<md-card>` and `<image>` tags. My output is not responsive on tablet or mobile screens, showing a  scrollbar instead of the next line. What's wrong with my code and how can I make it responsive?

```
<p>Show Menus</p>
<div layout="row" layout-margin >
  <md-card  ng-repeat="menu in sampleMenus">
   <md-card>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="md-card-image" alt="image caption"/>
    <md-card-content >
     <h2>{{menu.displayName}}</h2>
     <p>{{menu.type}}</p>
    </md-card-content>
       </md-card >
  </md-card>
</div>
```

Screenshots: [image: Desktop View]

[image: ![Tab View and mobile nearly same]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may help your cause.
http://codepen.io/sstorie/pen/myJWxQ
The key is those two classes added to the parent and the img in each card

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but please provide the source code here at StackOverflow or you could create a snippet here instead of CodePen. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 7):

You can use the flex(width for row, height for column) attribute to declare md-card size and layout-wrap on the parent container. Layout-align might help your cause as well.

```
<div layout="row" layout-margin layout-wrap layout-align="center center">
     <md-card flex="25"> //25% of parent
                //content 
     </md-card>
</div>
```

Check out the documentation for more options.

Comment: @ Matthew Can you Please Provide a Plunker with some example ?

Comment: Change:

<div layout="row" layout-margin > to <div layout="row" layout-margin layout-wrap layout-align="center center">

Comment: `layout-wrap` helped me achieve what I wanted. Thanks a ton!